# Conditionally remove rows based on date and time

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to implement a way to filter this dataframe `df`

```
structure(list(Name = c("Jim", "Jane", "Jose", "Matt", "Mickey", 
"Tom", "Peter", "Jane", "Jim", "Jose"), Progress = c("65", "20", 
"80", "20", "65", "45", "20", "70", "25", "80"), EndDate = c("11/25/2018 16:45", 
"11/25/2018 18:05", "11/25/2018 14:20", "12/1/2018 22:52", "11/29/2018 18:15", 
"12/2/2018 15:27", "11/26/2018 12:07", "11/30/2018 11:18", "11/29/2018 18:04", 
"11/29/2018 21:12")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to filter it such that if there are duplicate responses in the `Name` column like how Jim appears twice I would like to keep the row that has the earliest date and time according to the `EndDate` column ONLY if the `Progress` column value is greater than 70. Otherwise I want to take the row that has a later date and time in the `EndDate` column.

Comment: It's okay, what i meant is that editing your question makes it clear for everybody.   Very rarely people checks comments on other people's answers

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Yes, I figured I could not include that because the previous dataframe did not have those date formats and did not want to invalidate some people's answers. Is it usually best to change full question and example dataframe even if it invalidates previous answers?

Comment: Although, it is good to have a well constructed question with all patterns included beforehand, I understand that the big data can have some issues like the one you mentioned.  In that case, I would edit the question if it is not too much of a change or create a new question (if the question becomes entirely different).  The issue with notifying only a single person's answer is that others won't know the issue and may not be able to change the answer.  In this case, you alerted the user, he changed and confirmed while others don't know even whether their solution works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we first convert `EndDate` to date time object using `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` then we `group_by` `Name` and select row with minimum `EndDate` if `Progress > 70` and number of rows for each `Name` is more than 1 and maximum `EndDate` otherwise. If there is only one row for the `Name` then we select only that one by default.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(EndDate = parse_date_time(EndDate,c("%m-%d-%y %H:%M","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  slice(ifelse(n() > 1, 
        ifelse(any(Progress > 70), which.min(EndDate), which.max(EndDate)), 1))


#  Name   Progress EndDate            
#  <chr>  <chr>    <dttm>             
#1 Jane   70       2018-11-30 11:18:00
#2 Jim    25       2018-11-29 18:04:00
#3 Jose   80       2018-11-25 14:20:00
#4 Matt   20       2018-12-01 22:52:00
#5 Mickey 65       2018-11-29 18:15:00
#6 Peter  20       2018-11-26 12:07:00
#7 Tom    45       2018-12-02 15:27:00
```

Comment: I received a note when I ran this on my actual very large dataset that '711 failed to parse'. What does this refer to?

Comment: @M76 most probably it means there are certain `EndDate` values which it was not able to convert to datetime using `mdy_hm` from `lubridate`. Maybe they are in different format than shown ?

Comment: Yep that's it. For some reason some are in this format `11/25/18 16:10` and I don't know why, but if I convert them to the other format would the function work? Also, based on the code right now do you think it's working with this format `11/25/18 16:10` or this format `2018-12-02 15:27:00`

Comment: @M76 Currently, code is working for  `11/25/18 16:10` and `11/25/2018 16:10` . `mdy_hm` should work for `18` as well as `2018`. Do you have any date types apart from these two formats?

Comment: No just the only way dates are presented are in one of these 2 formats: `2018-12-02 15:27:00` and `11/25/18 16:10`

Comment: then use `parse_date_time` and specify those two formats. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! Can you also add a final ) to `("%m-%d-%y %H:%M","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`? It's missing one

Answer (score 3):

Based on the condition, we convert the 'EndDate' to `DateTime` class, then `arrange` by 'Name', 'EndDate', grouped by 'Name' `if` the `first` element of 'Progres' is greater than 70 return index 1 or `else` the last row index in `slice` to subset the rows

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%  
   mutate(EndDate = mdy_hm(EndDate)) %>%
   # if there are multiple formats
   # mutate(EndDate = anytime::anytime(EndDate)) %>%
   arrange(Name, EndDate) %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>%
   slice(if(first(Progress) > 70) 1 else n())
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Name [7]
#  Name   Progress EndDate            
#  <chr>  <chr>    <dttm>             
#1 Jane   70       2018-11-30 11:18:00
#2 Jim    25       2018-11-29 18:04:00
#3 Jose   80       2018-11-25 14:20:00
#4 Matt   20       2018-12-01 22:52:00
#5 Mickey 65       2018-11-29 18:15:00
#6 Peter  20       2018-11-26 12:07:00
#7 Tom    45       2018-12-02 15:27:00
```

NOTE: if there are multiple 'DateTime' formats, one option is `anytime::anytime` instead of `mdy_hm`

Answer (score 1):

An (of course) this can also be done using `data.table`

**sample data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Jim", "Jane", "Jose", "Matt", "Mickey", 
                        "Tom", "Peter", "Jane", "Jim", "Jose"), Progress = c("65", "20", 
                                                                             "80", "20", "65", "45", "20", "70", "25", "80"), EndDate = c("11/25/2018 16:45", 
                                                                                                                                          "11/25/2018 18:05", "11/25/2018 14:20", "12/1/2018 22:52", "11/29/2018 18:15", 
                                                                                                                                          "12/2/2018 15:27", "11/26/2018 12:07", "11/30/2018 11:18", "11/29/2018 18:04", 
                                                                                                                                          "11/29/2018 21:12")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**code**

```
#create the data.table (can also be done using setDT(df) )
dt <- as.data.table( df )
#set the dates to a proper POSIXct-format
dt[, EndDate := as.POSIXct( EndDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") ]
#order omn EndDate (by reference!)
setorder( dt, EndDate )
#summarise by Name, if first Progress >70 then keep it, else keep last Progress
dt[ , list( Progress = ifelse( Progress[1] > 70, Progress[1], Progress[.N] ) ), by = .(Name)][]
```

**benchmarks**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  data.table = {
    dt[, EndDate := as.POSIXct( EndDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") ]
    setorder( dt, EndDate )
    dt[ , list( Progress = ifelse( Progress[1] > 70, Progress[1], Progress[.N] ) ), by = .(Name)][]
  },
  tidyverse1 = {
    df %>%  
      mutate(EndDate = mdy_hm(EndDate)) %>%
      arrange(Name, EndDate) %>% 
      group_by(Name) %>%
      slice(if(first(Progress) > 70) 1 else n())
  },
  tidyverse2 = {
    df %>%
      mutate(EndDate = mdy_hm(EndDate)) %>%
      group_by(Name) %>%
      slice(ifelse(n() > 1, 
                   ifelse(any(Progress > 70), which.min(EndDate), which.max(EndDate)), 1))
  }
)


# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# data.table 1.654241 2.030820 2.709023 2.556978 2.782023 30.36590   100
# tidyverse1 6.847731 7.218286 8.742247 7.516838 8.034861 72.00902   100
# tidyverse2 6.173201 6.506398 7.286639 6.764582 7.088591 52.10180   100
```